# Импорт пакетов или конкретных типов из них

Tags: java, package

Доброго времени суток!

У меня такой вопрос по java. Обычно просматривая чужой код, я вижу, что импортируются не все пакеты целиком, а только конкретные типы из них. Почему бы не импортировать весь пакет, чтобы не писать кучу import по одной на каждый нужный тип? Чем это хуже?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Основная причина - в избежании конфликтов имен классов.

Допустим, у вас есть пакет `a.b.c` с классами `A`, `B` и `C`. И пакет `x.y.z` с классами `M`, `N` и... `C`.

Допустим, мы импортируем классы `B` и `N`. Мы можем импортировать их правильно:

```
import a.b.c.B;
import x.y.z.N;
```

а можем полениться и написать:

```
import a.b.c.*;
import x.y.z.*;
```

В первом случае все будет хорошо. А во втором возникнет конфликт имен между классами `a.b.c.C` и `x.y.z.C`. Поскольку существует много достаточно типовых имен классов (особенно интерфейсов, типа каких-нибудь `Event`, `Listener`, `Command` и т.п.), стоит импортировать их явно, дабы избежать конфликта.

Comment: Плюс общая неопределенность импорта. Класс есть, а откуда он - не поймешь. Или наоборот, гадаешь, что из импорта пришло.

Импорты, как вступительная секция класса, должны четко формировать область видимости класса, чтобы любой разработчик видел конкретные импорты.

Answer (score 0):

1. Памяти то больше съест
2. Современные иде автоматически сами пишут импорт (idea по крайней мере точно). И какая разница для иде писать по импорту для каждого класса, или импортировать целый пакет? *(основная причина)*

Comment: >Памяти то больше съест

Современные компиляторы, наверное, достаточно умны, чтобы реально импортировать только типы, которые использованы в коде.

>И какая разница для иде писать по импорту для каждого класса, или импортировать целый пакет?

Один import всего пакета выглядит будет занимать одну строчку, а сто импортов для каждого типа - сто строчек.

Comment: > (основная причина)

Nope...